# How do i add custom fields to my themes template file?

Tags: custom-field, customization

I am using 4 custom fields and display the custom fields in my theme page by

```
$quote_text_1 = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'quote_text_1', true);
$quote_text_1_author = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'quote_text_1_author', true);
echo '<p>'.$quote_text_1.'<br/>'.$quote_text_1_author .'</p>';

$quote_text_2 = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'quote_text_2', true);
$quote_text_2_author = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'quote_text_2_author', true);
 echo '<p>'.$quote_text_2.'<br/>'.$quote_text_2_author.'</p>';
```

How can I add the custom fields to specific theme template page, so the user knows he/she can use these fields?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are looking for a solution to conditionally display your custom fields on public facing pages (non-edit page), you can use WordPress [Conditional Tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags#Is_a_Page_Template).

```
if ( is_page_template('template-name.php') ) { 
    // Execute Your Code
}
```

Comment: sorry but i meant the edit-page. On creating a new specific template page i like to have the 4 custom fields ready to be filled in.

Comment: Second option I notice once you have used a custom field option it is available in a dropdown. On a new theme setup these custom fields are not yet used, so how do i make the options

Comment: ok i ended up using custom meta boxen.